# Vim mapping copy to system clipboard

Tags: linux, vim, clipboard

I've gotten vim to copy to the system clipboard (xsel) by pressing the following keys: `"+y`. Now I want to map that to the following key combiation: `Ctrl+Shift+c`, since that's what termite, the terminal I use, has set as defaults, and I want to keep some consistency.

This isn't working, and I don't understand why.

```
vnoremap <C-S-c> "+y
```

I know I can use some of the alternatives from the vim wiki, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: This Q may be more appropriate on the related site http://vi.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of that particular branch. Will do as you suggested.

Comment: You might want to look at [cua-mode](https://github.com/fabi1cazenave/cua-mode.vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong. your `<c-s-c>` mapping doesn't work in your terminal, because in terminal vim. the `c-c` and `c-s-c` have same keycodes. You can prove it by typing `<c-v><c-c>` and `<c-v><c-s-c>` in INSERT mode.

You mentioned vim wiki, I am not sure if you have read [this wiki entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim). It should help you.